# Storing HTML based e-mail templates?

Tags: php, html, email, templates, mailgun

I have recently begun using Mailgun in place of my own e-mail server, where my website instead submits outgoing e-mails using CURL. They supply several e-mail templates that can be used, which I have modified to include relevant details to users.

I only have several templates and currently have no reliance on a database, why I would like to avoid that approach if possible. I am thinking the best option would be to just store them in individual HTML files such as "newuser_template.html", use `file_get_contents()` and replace placeholders with values and then submit it to Mailgun to be sent.

Is there any other approaches that may work better that don't require a database? I would like to keep the implementation as slim as possible, so avoiding Smartys and other templating engines as well.

[MailGun Transactional E-Mail Templates](http://blog.mailgun.com/transactional-html-email-templates/)

Comment: why not make the templates actual php file you include and set variables.

Comment: That actually seems like a pretty decent idea as well. I vaguely remember coming across something a while back where the person had a html/text template defined in a variable but they had used some unusual approach that looked great. I can't remember what it was now, why I was hoping I may be overlooking a better option.